# moveit collision avoidance

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using default IK planner (KDLplugin) for planning the path for ABB_IRB4600  robot using moveIt RViz plugin. When i import an object and make the robot movement to avoid that object by publishing current scene in RViz . The movements of the robot becomes very weired. Is there a way to refine the movements of the robot during collision avoidance of the object in the planning scene. I tried to incease the planning attempts and the planning time but haven't acheived any good result.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262379/moveit-collision-avoidance/) by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the RViz Motion Planning panel, under the Context tab, try picking a different OMPL algorithm.  I find that RRTConnectkConfigDefault works well out of the box.

---

Originally posted by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) with karma: 525 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on 2017-06-01**:
RRTConnectkConfigDefault looks good. thanks but still movements of the robot are not so refined as i want to have. It should go around the obstacle but it moves a bit far from the obstacle. any suggestion how to get linear movements around the obstacle

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-06-07**:
You could also have a look at ROS-I's stomp implementation: https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_moveit .
This uses a whole different planning approach and should yield "nicer" trajectories.

**Comment by [Muneeb](https://answers.ros.org/users/29399/muneeb/) on 2017-06-09**:
I switched to stomp planner. The trajectories are really nice when i plan and execute using RVIZ plugin even around the obstacle. but now i am having problem with sending pose values since i think its only works with joint values.